# Evaluate $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\left[\left(\frac{1}{\sin^{-1}(x)}\right)^2-\frac{1}{x^2}\right],$

Tags: calculus, limits, taylor-expansion

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\left(\frac{1}{\sin^{-1}(x)}\right)^2-\frac{1}{x^2}\right]$$ 
i am a class 12th student and this is my first question on math.SE . This question is part of a previous assignment. I have tried in this way ,
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{x^2-(\sin{x}^{-1})^2}{x^2 (\sin{x}^{-1})^2}\right]$$
$$as\; we\; know\; that\qquad \sin^{-1}{x}=\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^5}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)$$ 
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{x^2-\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^5}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)^2}{x^2 \left(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^5}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)^2}\right]$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{1-\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^4}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)^2}{\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^5}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)^2}\right]$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{\left(1-\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^4}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)\right)\left(1+\left(1+\frac{x^2}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^4}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)\right)}{\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^5}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)^2}\right]$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\left[\frac{(-1)\left(\frac{x^2}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^4}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)\left(2+\frac{x^2}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^4}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)}{\left(x+\frac{x^3}{3!}1^2+\frac{x^5}{5!}1^23^2+\cdots\right)^2}\right]$$
$$=\frac{-1}{3}$$
Is this right? and Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Something appears to be missing. Is there supposed to be an argument on the $\sin^{-1}$? Also, do you mean $1/\sin $ or do you mean $\arcsin$?

Comment: Please read https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to write Math here. Kindly take a quick tour and learn it. Also please add some context and what you have tried so far to the question. Questions with no context are likely to be closed. Thank you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lhôpital-rule-or-series-expansion

Comment: Hint: remember that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} =1$.

Comment: @JoshuaZ  yup I know that, but can anyone solve this please

Comment: Ok, next suggestion: Put everything over  a common denominator and see what you get.

Comment: Please remove the hold , i have formatted the question correctly. @5xum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that
$$ \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1. $$
Under $\sin^{-1}x\to x$, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\left[\left(\frac{1}{\sin^{-1}(x)}\right)^2-\frac{1}{x^2}\right]\\
&=&\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\left[\frac{1}{x^2}-\left(\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)^2\right]=\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2x}\\
&=&\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{(\sin x-x)(\sin x+x)}{x^2\sin^2x}=\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\frac{\sin x+x}{x}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}\\
&=&2\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}
\end{eqnarray}
and the rest follows [Are all limits solvable without L'Hôpital Rule or Series Expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387333/are-all-limits-solvable-without-lh%C3%B4pital-rule-or-series-expansion).

Comment: Sorry , but I didn't understand the first step. How did you write [(1/sin^{-1}(X))^2 ] as      -[1/sin(X)]^2 ?

Comment: Also how do you write these complicated maths in JavaScript , it is tiring, especially on smartphone.

Comment: @SudiptaHalder, changing variable.